# OpenGL bad texture size

Tags: java, opengl, size, textures

```
Texture texture = loadTexture("main_menu/bg");    
texture.bind();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2i(1, 1);

        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2i(1, 720);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2i(1280, 720);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2i(1280, 1);
    glEnd();
```

I use LWJGL library with slick2D. I am rendering textures with above way, but textures has incorrect position. I have 1280x720 fullscreen window and I render background texture over window but texture is reduced at X axis to 2/3 of window and at Y axis at 3/4 of window.

I am adding setup of openGL, so here it is:

```
WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280;
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720;

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho(0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();       
glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
```

And here is method for loading textures:

```
private Texture loadTexture(String key) {
try {
    return TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(
            new File("res/" + key + ".png")));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGL1, texture widths and heights must be integral powers of 2, e.g.

128x128, 256x256, 512x64, ...

Yours seem to be 1280x720, which is not one. :)
Note that your dimensions don't matter in OpenGL2.

Comment: If you use non power of 2 textures while they are not supported the texture turns up white, it has nothing to do with the size on screen.